# How to produce display style fractions in plain tex

Tags: plain-tex, fractions

How to produce display style fractions in **plain tex**?

I know that plain tex uses `\over` for fractions, for example `{1}\over{2}`.

But how to do displaystyle fractions? I tried to use `\displaystyle` and it rendered nothing but a bit of unrecognizable stuff.

Note. My intention was to deal with Manim's math formulas.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you'd shown how you used `\displaystyle`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fraction notation is, in my opinion, the most infelicitous choice made by Knuth in designing TeX.

The `\over` command takes ***no*** argument at all and your `{1}\over{2}` syntax has no advantage: try

```
$$3+{1}\over{2}$$
```

and see by yourself that the result is not what you may think. The syntax for `\over` is

```
{<numerator> \over <denominator>}
```

and the braces are *mandatory* unless the fraction is the only object in a math formula. Thus

```
the fraction $1\over 2$ represents a half
```

is OK, but

```
the expression $1+1\over2$ represents three halves
```

is incorrect either in the formula or in the text.

How do we apply `\displaystyle`? Surely not with

```
{\displaystyle 1\over 2}
```

because this would only apply `\displaystyle` to the numerator.

The next attempt would be

```
\displaystyle{1\over 2}
```

but of course this would apply the style to everything that follows.

In order to apply the style to just the fraction, do

```
{\displaystyle{1\over2}}
```

Can you define a shorthand such as `\dover`? No. It's impossible to define commands that behave like `\over`, `\atop`, `\above` and the related `\...withdelims` variations.

Do yourself a favor and issue

```
\def\frac#1#2{{\begingroup#1\endgroup\over#2}}
\def\dfrac#1#2{{\displaystyle\frac{#1}{#2}}}
```

so you can type

```
\frac{1}{2}
```

and easily modify it into

```
\dfrac{1}{2}
```

should the need arise.

<sub>Why the `\begingroup...\endgroup`? Because assignments done in the numerator might (and would) leak in the denominator.</sub>

Comment: So did LaTeX define ```\frac``` like you did?

Comment: @youthdoo Yes, I took the code straight from it

Answer (score 6):

Your example of using `\over` is bad, right example is `{1\over2+3}` or, if the fraction is single object in the math mode then you can omit the braces and write `$1\over2+3$`. In display mode, `\over` creates display fraction. In text mode you can write `$\displaystyle{1\over2+3}$`. If you write only `$\displaystyle 1\over 2+3$` then only nominator is in the display style, because each part of fraction has set its own math-style. You can read [Typesetting math in OpTeX](http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/optex-math.pdf), especially the section 1.4.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use `{\displaystyle {1 \over 2}}` while in inline math mode. Conversely, if you need to create a text-style fraction while in display math mode, I suggest you use `{\textstyle {1 \over 2}}`.

[image]

```
%% inline-style math mode is the default:
\centerline{%
  $1 \quad {1 \over 2} \quad {\displaystyle {1 \over 2}} \quad 2$}

%% display-style math mode is the default:
$$ 1 \quad {1 \over 2} \quad {\textstyle {1 \over 2}}    \quad 2$$

\bye
```

Do observe that both `\textstyle` and `\displaystyle` are *switching* commands and don't take an explicit argument. This means that their scope is through to the end of the current TeX group. Hence, one should write `{\textstyle {1 \over 2}}` rather than `\textstyle{{1 \over 2}}`.